# Printing numbers after decimal point

Tags: c#, decimal-point

How can i print the numbers of a float/double variable after the decimal point?
For example for `435.5644` it will output `5644`.

Answer (score 4):

try with

```
fraction = value - (long) value;
```

or :

```
fraction = value - Math.Floor(value);
```

Comment: Better than the solution I was in the middle of typing!

Comment: I'am happy to help you Liam and user1014842

Comment: this are not only the parts after the decimal point. fraction is btw 0.56439999999997781. Think that is not what OP wants.

Comment: Go with the second option, converting to `long` may have overflow issues with certain numbers (albiet very large numbers).

Comment: The double representation problems are not solved there either. see my comment above on the result of the calculation (fraction)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
  double d = 435.5644;
  int n = (int)d;

  var v = d - n;

  string s = string.Format("{0:#.0000}", v);

  var result = s.Substring(1);
```

result: 5644

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: reference to another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-part-of-a-number-in-javascript)
You can do the following:

```
double d = 435.5644;
float f = 435.5644f;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(d % 1, 4) * 10000);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(f % 1, 4) * 10000);
```

That will give you the integer part you looking for.

Best is to do it as Aghilas Yakoub answered, however, here below another option using string handling. Assuming all amounts will have decimals and that decimal separator is a dot (.) you just need to get the index 1.

```
double d = 435.5644;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString().Split('.')[1]);

float f = 435.5644f;
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString().Split('.')[1]);
```

Otherwise you may get a Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Nice idea, but as you stated will have some problems when integers are passed in