# Check if number's decimal is higher than .5 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, decimal

How can I check if a number's decimal value is higher than .5 in JavaScript?

For example, I need to know if a number's decimal point is between .5 (higher) and .9 (equal or lower).

Some example numbers: 0.6, 2.7, 4.9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get decimal portion of a number with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var num = 5.7;

if((num % 1) > 0.5)
    console.write("remainder is greater than 0.5");
```

Comment: I don't know why but this returns false:
(37.99999999999999999999 % 1) > 0.5

Comment: @Gamby because floating point numbers are hard.

Answer (score 5):

Round the number and check whether the result is larger than the number:

```
n < Math.round(n)
```

[`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) rounds the number up if the decimal part is `.5` or higher.

**Note:** The result will be `true` if the decimal part of the number is `>= .5`, not just `> .5`.

To account for precision errors, you probably would also have to floor `n`:

```
Math.floor(n) < Math.round(n)
```

Comment: Doesn't it use banker's rounding though?  3.5 is rounded to 4, 2.5 is rounded to 2 in banker's rounding.  I might be wrong

Comment: Sorry, ignore that - it rounds 0.5 up

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: Still a a good point though... the question seems to be "higher than .5", not "higher than or equal to .5" :-/

Comment: So this isn't correct in the case the number is exactly x.5

Comment: @Cofey: Please clarify, do you want to test for `> .5` or or `>= .5`?

Comment: I already have a check for .5 -- I just need it if it's over that.

Comment: @Cofey: Ok. Strictly speaking it tests for `>= .5`, just be aware of that. And as always when working with floating point numbers, be aware of precision errors.