# Get decimals of a number

Tags: javascript

`10.1 - Math.floor(10.1)` returns `0.09999999999999964`

I was expecting to get `0.1`. How can this be achieved?

```
console.log(10.1 - Math.floor(10.1));
```

Comment: You have many response here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript

Comment: 10.1 - 10 is also not 0.1 btw

Comment: Oh. I guess all my calculators are broken then. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is the limitation of using binaries to store decimal numbers, you lose precision.

Comment: I see. Thanks @Alic. I will read up on this.

Comment: Math in JS is quite a headache; 0.1 + 0.2 is not 0.3

Comment: @Lautaro Here's something to get you started: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: Thank you @Alic. Now i understand why and can work with it. Great!