# Can I check on what an integer ends in Javascript

Tags: javascript, gravityforms

I want to remove the decimals after a price if it ends on ',00'. If it ends on anything else it should remain. I'll have to be able to see on what the price ends to do so, but how do I achieve this in Javascript?

My idea was checking if the price ended on 00 and removing it in an if statement.

```
function gformFormatMoney(text, isNumeric){ 
if(!gf_global.gf_currency_config)
return text;

var currency = new Currency(gf_global.gf_currency_config);
var unformatted = currency.toMoney(text, isNumeric);
var formatted;
var formatting = unformatted%10;
if(formatting == 00) {

} 

return unformatted;
}
```

^This gives a error 'Octal litterals with the prefix 0 are not allowed'

Comment: An `int` has 0 decimals. You probably mean a `float` or `double`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get decimal portion of a number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript)

Comment: convert the integer to string and check the last 2 indexes using indexof(). and convert it back to integer

Comment: Have you tried anything? please share your code.

Comment: @UshmaJoshi Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't an integer, but a string.

I fixed it by doing:

```
function gformFormatMoney(text, isNumeric){
if(!gf_global.gf_currency_config)
    return text;

var currency = new Currency(gf_global.gf_currency_config);
var unformatted = currency.toMoney(text, isNumeric);
var formatted = unformatted.replace(',00', '');

return formatted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use toFixed.

as for :

```
let num = 50.00;
num.toFixed(2).includes('.00') ? num.toFixed() :num.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What about `40.40` returning `40.4`?

Comment: Right, I have fixed my answer. but this is only for the display of the number, at the end it is the same number arithmetically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your numbers as a float, fix it to 2 decimals (in all cases), and remove any matches for `(.00)`. Something like this could work:

```js
function fixFloat(num){
  return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2).replace('.00', '');
}

console.log(fixFloat(20.00));
console.log(fixFloat(40.40));
console.log(fixFloat(30.01));
```

Please be aware that this will return a ***string***. If you wish to convert this back to a number, you'll need to parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type is not string , the trailing zeros after decimal will be removed. If it is a string use `parseInt` to convert to number

```js
let price = 20.00;
console.log(price)

let price1 = '40.00'
console.log(parseInt(price1, 10))

let price2 = '40.00'
console.log(parseFloat(price2, 10))
```

Comment: Should've added this to the question, but I tried this and it didn't show the prices in the frontend