# Sort a list by the second number after a dot

Tags: javascript, php, sorting

I need to sort a list by the second batch number with JavaScript.

This is how it looks like now:

```
1101.19
1201.17
1301.09
```

What I need is:

```
1301.09
1201.17
1101.19
```

As I am still learning to program I can't figure out the issue. But need it at work.

Can someone help me understand the process of how to do it?

Comment: Sorry! Edited the post. I'm using JS

Comment: Is this an array? ["1101.19", "1201.17", "1301.09"]

Comment: Would you use the `reverse` method on an array? Like this: `[1101.19, 1201.17, 1301.09].sort().reverse().join('\n')`

Comment: Do all numbers come in the same format or can you have a whole number mixed? Do they come as strings or number objects. Have you tried using `sort` - if so, what stopped you?

Comment: What's the meaning of the part after the dot? Should it be interpreted as an integer or a floating point value?

Comment: The part after the dot is the year of production, so an integer.

Comment: Thanks, for all your answers and questions, unfortunately my workplace is not yet set up to work properly, and I'll have to wait until tomorrow to test anything..

Comment: Tomorrow has come, have you had a chance to look at this again?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. We figured that we can find a much simpler solution through dataTables, and sort by createdDate in the backgound

Comment: @Codebelle you could still check the solutions given here and could approve the best suit answer which could be implemented in the clien side.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array depending on the decimal part. Here is the solution

Sort the array by selecting the decimal part of the number inside the sort function.

You can get the decimal part of any number by taking modulus operation with 0.1. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript).

```js
const arr = [1101.19, 1201.17, 1301.09, 1201.20];
arr.sort((a, b) => {return (a % 1 - b % 1)});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Number or string?

Comment: @Adriani6 oops there was was small error inside sort function. Corrected that. Please check

Comment: `.sort` mutates the original array, so no need of arr2 or sort a copy of array `[...arr].sort((a, b) => a % 1 - b % 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each element before sort and compare second parts

```js
let array = ["1101.69", "1701.57", "1301.09"];
array.sort((a,b)=>{
  let pair1 = a.split('.');
  let pair2 = b.split('.');
  return ( parseInt(pair1[1]) < parseInt(pair2[1])) ? -1 : 1;
});
console.log(array);
```