# Jquery get last number jquery get function

Tags: jquery

How to get last number with jquery? For example 25.50 how to get last 50?
How to get first number too? for example 25 `enter code here`

Thanks for help. Happy coding

For example lets say I have a variable and its 25.50 ok?
I need to get 50 and if 50 =< 50 make it 25 I mean 25.00 if 50 > 50 make it +1 I mean 26

Comment: use split function for ex. var data = input.split('.');  

var a = data [0]; // 25
var b = data [1]; 50

Comment: So you want to [round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) the number?

Comment: Seems like you're searching for [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Comment: @NullDev Yes dear but I make 50 too less

Comment: I mean math.round make 50 more but I need 50 too make less 51 ets more

Comment: @Mychannel See my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get decimal portion of a number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: You don't need jQuery for that.

If I understand correctly you want to [`round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) the number, but make it round down on `<= .5` and up on `> .5`. This can be done by negating both `Math.round` as well as the input:

```js
let round = num => (-Math.round(-num));

console.log(round(25.50))
console.log(round(12.60));
console.log(round(9.40));
```

This is possible, because [as standardized in the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.round), `Math.round()` rounds towards positive infinity.

> 5. Return the [integral Number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#integral-number) closest to *n*, preferring the Number closer to +∞ in the case of a tie.