# How to get the correct output for the given set of values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am working on javascript here I am having some function which should pass all the test cases given in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jkxhnc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I just want to divide the number after point by `60`

Here is the code so far I tried

```
 convert(min: any) {
    return min.split(".")[1] / 60;
  }
```

Any my input is

```
console.log(this.convert(2.0));
console.log(this.convert(2.15));
console.log(this.convert(2.3));
console.log(this.convert(2.45));
```

and my output should give like this

```
2.0
2.25
2.5
2.75
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get decimal portion of a number with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512306/get-decimal-portion-of-a-number-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its not helping me.

Comment: "Is not helping me" is not something we can work with. _Why_ is it not helping you? If you use that method to get the fraction of the number instead of `min.split(".")[1]` (which doesn't work because you can't call `.split()` on a number), it should work fine.

Comment: @kishan, check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `split` a Number type. First convert your number to string, then split and then return it to number again. Refer the below function.

```
findHrsToMins(min: any) {
    min = String(min);
    return Number(min.split(".")[1] / 60);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Function:**

```
findHrsToMins(min: any) {
    const parts = min.toString().split(".");
    const mins = +parts[1];
    if (mins > 0 && mins < 10) mins *= 10; // Newly added
    return +parts[0] + (mins > 0 ? mins / 60 : 0);
}
```

Working demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m5r3ot?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Hi Zunayed Shahriar, Thanks for the answer but its failing in the testcase of 1.3, 2.3,3.3...7.3 the output should be 1.5,2.5,3.5...7.5

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Initial input is pretty weird in your case. I suppose `x.59` is the maximum there.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal

In current function you are returning only division after decimal and it is a division of fraction
You need to add first part of the split (full hours) and get minutes instead of fraction of hour before division as well to get proper return.

```js
function normalConvert(num: number){
    const [hour, hourFraction] = Number(num).toFixed(2).split(".")
    return +hour + ((+hourFraction * 100) / 60 / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have made it easier for yourself by typing the argument of the function, since that would help Typescript tell you what was going on.

```
findHrsToMins(min: number) {
    const hour = parseFloat(min.toString().split(".")[0]);

    const minutes = ((min * 100 - hour * 100) / 60).toFixed(2).split(".")[1];

    return `${hour}.${minutes}`;
  }
```